# Can we calculate the derivative of a distribution function with respect to its parameters?

Tags: derivatives, probability-distributions

I am asking a very basic question. Can we calculate the derivative of a density function with respect to its parameters, mean and variance? Can we calculate the derivative of a distribution function with respect to its parameters, mean and variance?

Comment: I don't think so because the density function is a function of a continuous variable and the mean and variance are fixed constants,

Comment: Differentiation is involved in maximum likelihood estimations. That may be worth checking out.

Comment: The question that comes first to my mind is: What is your goal ?

Comment: My goal is to calculate the derivative of a copula density with respect to the marginal parameter. Because we have marginal distribution inside copula, my question is do we have to calculate the derivative of that marginal wrt to that marginal parameter and if yes how do we do that.

Comment: Mean and variance are the usual  parameters for the normal, not for most families of distributions. That said, for the usual nice distributions, the distribution function varies smoothly as mean or variance vary, so sure you can differentiate.